# In python list consist an element 0 is not included in filter function,Why?

Tags: python, filter, lambda, functional-programming

```
>>> print filter(lambda x:x,[4,0,4,0,0,2])
[4, 4, 2]
```

Comment: What are you expecting the code to do?

Comment: Because Python isn't Ruby and `0 == False #=> True` so filter lambda function reject all `0`.

Answer (score 4):

The result of your function (`lambda x:x`) is treated as a bool, and `bool(0)` is `False`. The job of `filter()` is to exclude all elements for which the function returns `False`. From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

> Construct a list from those elements of iterable for which function returns true.

Answer (score 0):

@NPE has already given an explanation of the behavior you are observing

On a side note, your expression

```
>>> print filter(lambda x:x,[4,0,4,0,0,2])
```

can be equivalently written as

```
>>> filter(None,[4,0,4,0,0,2])
```